# CSS Style Sheet: A, TD, TH, and Table tags

Tags: css

I am having an issue with my CSS. When I view my page in Apple Safari, the page is styled correctly. However, when I view my page in Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox, the page is not styled correctly. Primarily, the a, table, th, and td tags are not working in Firefox and Google Chrome. Everything else seems to be working well.

Here is my style sheet:

```
a{
margin-left:300px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

br{
clear: left;
}

font{
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

label{
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
float: left;
display: block;
width: 300px;
}

legend{
color:#ff0000;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
}

table{
margin-left:300px;
}

td{
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

textarea{
width: 300px;
height: 150px;
}

th{
color:#ff0000;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.width{
width: 300px;
}
```

Here is my entire HTML page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>ACISS | Statute Search</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="statute.css" />

</head>

<body>
<font>
Your search yielded the following results:
</font>
<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ACISS Statute</th>
<th>ACISS Charge</th>
<th>UCR</th>
</tr>
<?php 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['ACISS_statute']?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['ACISS_charge_name']?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['ACISS_UCR']?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
<br />
<a href="http://localhost:80/statute_search/">Click Here to Search Again</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `font-family` doesn't really need to be declared that much...

Comment: @Andrew Peacock: Made me look at the code again. And wow, `font { font-family: ... }`, really?

Comment: only the css is not very helpful, you need to elaborate the question a bit more. It could be the way the html is formatted not the css...

Answer (score 2):

Without the HTML I can't be 100% sure what the problem is, but my best guess would be that it has something to do with the browser default settings. By resetting them with something like [the html5 doctor reset sheet](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/) everything may then look the same cross-browser.